# FormatTime command messes %A_DDD% format. E.g. I can get ’We14’ and ’We7’ instead of ’Wed’ and ’10on’ instead of ’Mon’

Tags: autohotkey

I use [FormatTime](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FormatTime.htm) command to make timestamps for my notebook notes and the formula that I generally use looks like this:

```
:*:ibsfo:: 
FormatTime, ExecutorTimeStamp,, h:mm tt, %A_DDD%. dd-MM-yyyy
SendInput |%ExecutorTimeStamp%| (1)| (2)| (3)| (4)|-`r{Left 21}
return
```

It is supposed to give an outcome like this:

```
|1:24 PM, Wed. 14-11-2012| (1)| (2)| (3)| (4)|-
```

but instead I get something like this:

```
|1:24 PM, We14. 14-11-2012| (1)| (2)| (3)| (4)|-
```

Same happens with other days of the week as well. Some more examples of such messed up results are:

```
We14, We7, SaP, We10, 10on, T2u, T4u
```

Why is this happening and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
:*:ibsfo::
FormatTime, ExecutorTimeStamp,, h:mm tt, ddd dd-MM-yyyy
SendInput %ExecutorTimeStamp%
return
```

Output:

```
6:41 PM, Wed 14-11-2012
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work. Any idea why it was giving that particular kind of mistakes?

Comment: Thanks. And sorry, I derped a little there with the answer. It’s done. : )

Answer (score 1):

> > Why is this happening

The parameter called 'format' expects certain key letters -or- a few special key words
to represent parts of a date/time.

%A_DDD% is interpreted as the name of one the days of the week, Sunday ... Saturday
The letters from whatever name are interpreted as more key letters.